# How to use Watermark in RDLC report

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I'm currently involved in the ABC project, and as part of our reporting requirements, I'm looking to incorporate watermarks into our RDLC reports. These watermarks will serve various purposes such as indicating draft status, adding branding elements, or ensuring confidentiality. By integrating watermarks into our reports, we aim to enhance the visual presentation while maintaining the clarity and professionalism of the content. My goal is to seamlessly integrate these watermarks into the report layout, ensuring they complement the primary information without causing distraction.

i am expecting good.